# What does `update_attribute` return if it fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, update-attributes, update-attribute

I have following piece of code

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if (@user.activation_status == "active") 
  #some code here 
  @user.update_attribute('activation_status' ,'inactive')  # Line 44
  #send mail to user that his account is Acivated
else

end
```

Is there any chance that `Line 44` could fail? Because database memory is full or network failure. What will happen in that case? If that creates a problem, what is a better way to avoid it? What does `update_attribute` return if it failed?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the source for `update_attribute`:

```
def update_attribute(name, value)
  send(name.to_s + '=', value)
  save(false)
end
```

You can see that it updates the requested attribute and then calls [save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001855) with `perform_validations` set to `false`. Therefore `update_attribute` would return `false` if any of the save callbacks (e.g. `before_save`) prevented the record from being saved by returning `false`.

If there was a lower level error such as out of memory at the database then I expect the database driver to raise this as an exception which would be passed up to your code.

Comment: what `update_attribute` will return i know what `update_attributes` does? `update_attribute` && `update_attributes` are two different methods. I would like to know about `update_attribute`

Comment: This answer is referring to **update_attribute**, I had made a typing mistake in the original version of the answer. `update_attribute` returns the value returned by `save`, as described in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If update_attributes fails, it will return false.  if you ignore the return value, you'll have no idea it happened either.  You can use update_attributes!, which in turn calls save!, which in turn raises an exception if something goes wrong.  While this is something you can't miss (unless you write catch-all rescue statements), if you don't catch it, it will fall through to Rails, and it will abort the request.

It's usually a good idea to check the return value.

Comment: - i know what `update_attributes` does i would like to know about `update_attribute`?

Comment: They both do the same thing.  Both update_attributes and update_attribute use the attr= assignments and then call save.

Comment: - You are wrong they don't do same thing `update_attributes` check validation before saving data and return false is object is invalid and true if it saved whereas `update_attribute` save data w/o checking validations.